# How Zariski topology is topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology it says that $V(I+J) = V(I) \cap V(J)$. Two questions:

1- Is my solution for this claim correct and rigorous: If $x$ is a zero of some $f \in I$ and some $g \in J$ then it is a zero of any linear combination of them over the ring $R$, so $V(I) \cap V(J) \subset V(I+J)$. If $x \in V(I+J)$ then $x \in V(I)$ and $\in V(J)$, since $I+J$ contains $I$ and $J$ as special cases?

2- How to generalize $V(I+J) = V(I) \cap V(J)$ to $V(\sum_i J_i) = \cap_i V(J_i)$, where sum and intersection is taken over an *arbitrary* set of indices?

Comment: The infinite intersection of closed sets works because any ideal of $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is finitely generated, so the intersection is in fact an intersection of finitely many closed sets.

Comment: your solution for two ideal is correct and can be used for arbitrary set of indices almost word by word. what is your problem in generalizing the solution?

Comment: The sum of an arbitrary collection of ideals makes sense: it is just the ideal generated by finite sums in $J_i$. In the noetherian case (as is often the case in classical algebraic geometry), any infinite sum of ideals can be expressed as a finite one.

Comment: @ali got it thanks